# Удаление содержимого атрибута class

Tags: html

Вот часть кода:

```
<nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu__list">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Информация</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Оставить отзыв</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Блог шерифа</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Гостиницы</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="menu__close"><img src="img/close.png" alt=""></a>
        <div class="logo">
          <a class="logo__link" href="index.html">
            <img class="logo__image" src="img/logo.png" width="138" height="70" alt="Седона">
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="menu__open"><img src="img/open.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Как мне быстро отредактировать `HTML` документ и удалить содержимое атрибута `class`? Т.е вместо `class="menu__open"` было - `class=""`.
И так во всем документе.
Спасибо!

Все значения атрибута `class` в документе могут быть разными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать замену по регулярному выражению `class="[^"]+"` на `class=""` через любую IDE или нормальный текстовый редактор.

Answer (score 5):

Удаление можно сделать при помощи [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
$('*').each(function(){ $(this).attr('class') && $(this).attr('class', '') })
$('*').each(function(){ $(this).removeAttr('class') })
```

Первый вариант дает результат `<div id="123" class></div>`, второй полностью удаляет у всех атрибут `class`. Получить `<div id="123" class=""></div>` невозможно, так как браузер сам подчистит пустое значение.

Так же можно удаление сделать и на чистом `javascript`:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
    var tag = tags[i];
    if (tag.attributes.getNamedItem('class')){
        var stub = document.createAttribute("class");
        stub.value = "";
        tag.attributes.setNamedItem(stub);
    }
}
```

Comment: ваш код зачистит вообще все, даже конструкции `class="my_class menu__open"`, что очень плохо когда нужно оставить **my_class**, а удалить только **menu__open**

Comment: @Dmitry, как я понял, необходимо удалить все значения атрибута `class`.

Comment: да, я тоже читал об этом, но что-то мне подсказывает, что **ТС** будет недоволен тем, что `CSS` слетит одним вызовом `JS`

Comment: Так и было запланировано :) Всем спасибо, проблему решил регулярками в ST:) Мне просто надо было удалить все значения классов, что бы написать свои)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
$('*').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass('menu__open') });
```

так мы удалим только упоминание о нужном классе, все остальные останутся на месте.